# CORS in a Rails app for jQueryUI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui, cors

I have a Rails app where I use jQuery UI Autocomplete to suggest product names when searching - this all works fine. However we have launched a separate forum app, which is in a sub-domain and I'd like to offer the same functionality there as well.

I have set up jQuery UI on the forum, and the demo code (where the data is present inline) works fine. However when I switch the source to my rails app `mysite.com/products/names` Chrome reports that the request was cancelled - this is of course because of cross-site requests, meaning I have to either JSONP or set up Cross-origin resource sharing.

After chatting in the Rails IRC Chat room, it is suggested I use CORS, so this is the option I am opting for.

I have added this to my application controller:

```
before_action :allow_cross_domain_access

def allow_cross_domain_access
  if request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
  # better way check origin
  # if request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"] && /^https?:\/\/(.*)\.some\.site\.com$/i.match(request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"])
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match,Auth-User-Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  end
end
```

And I have this as a starting point for the js:

```
$(function() {
    url = "http://www.mysite.com/products/names"
    $( "#search_bar" ).autocomplete(
    {
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        source: url,

    })
});
```

Any ideas where I need to go from here? For reference, here is the JSONP demo code from the docs:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                value: item.name
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Any ideas how I can adapt this to work with CORS please?

EDIT: What I've tried...

(1) Attempt using JSONP (not sure how to do it with CORS). This was giving me a `500 Internal Server Error` until I changed `name_startsWith` to `term`. Now looking at the response via Chrome's network tab in the developer tools, I am getting my suggestions come through ok in the response (eg: `["name1", "name2", "name3"]`, and under the preview tab show as:

```
0: "name1"
1: "name2"
2: "name3"
```

I guess I need to adjust `success` to get these to show as suggestions in the search bar:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#search_bar" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://www.mysite.com/products/names?jsonp_callback=?",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.name
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Here is the coffeescript I am using in my Rails app:

```
initialize = ->
  $('#search_bar').autocomplete
    source: $('#search_bar').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $(this).parents("form").submit()
    focus: (event, ui) ->
       $('#search_bar').val(ui.item.value)

$(document).ready initialize
```

And this is it converted to JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $('#search_bar').autocomplete({
    source: $('#search_bar').data('autocomplete-source'),
    select: function(event, ui) {
      return $(this).parents("form").submit();
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      return $('#search_bar').val(ui.item.value);
    }
  });
});
```

Ideally I'd like it to perform in the same way as it does in the parent app. Any ideas where I need to go from here?

Comment: I believe you already have the answer with you. the sample code which u have posted from jquery-ui  site will serve your purpose. under the source option in your autocomplete code, just create a ajax function as mentioned in the sample code and just provide the appropriate details in the ajax call. and the success block is where you need to construct your data for the autocomplete to  display. which can be defaulted to the code in the sample

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver I can't seem to get it to work. If I use the code as it is (with JSONP) I get '500 Internal Server Error' (under status in Chrome dev tools), but if I try to remove the jsonp datatype and remove ```?jsonp_callback=``` from the end of the URL I just get '200 cancelled' in the status bar. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: could you post the updated code which your trying at your end, just to verify if its syntactically correct or not.

Comment: Thanks @dreamweiver I have updated the question. I have managed to get the response now via the JSONP method, so not sure whether to continue with this or go down the CORS route? I guess I need to get the JS to show the suggestions sorted first and would appreciate your help here as I'm a total JS nube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed via IRC,

```
$( "#breed" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://yourservername.com/dogs/names",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            //console.log(data);
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return  item; 
            }));
          }
        });
      },
...
```

Your JSON didn't actually have "objects", just an array.. so each item can be returned as an item.. As you changed the term name, you have to change the parameter here too.

Fiddle was sent via IRC illustrating working code with your JSON data.

References: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp